# iOS PictureInPicture restoreUserInterface method isn't called after watching Youtube

Tags: ios, swift, picture-in-picture

I am implementing PiP for my app and I face a problem where `restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler` isn't called.

**Steps that produce the problem**

1. Play video in my app and enter PiP mode.
2. Open a video app (Youtube, Netflix) and play a video there.
3. Tap `restore` button on PiP to go back to our app
4. Here, the `restoreUserInterface` is not called.

You guys have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Hey @kcatstack did you get to the bottom of it? I am observing the same issue but it seems to be device specific for me